# Can somebody explain how does this program regarding enum works in java?

Tags: java, function, enums, scjp, ocpjp

Here's the code :

```
enum Status {

    STATUS_OPEN(10),
    STATUS_STARTED(11),
    STATUS_INPROGRESS(12);

    private final int status;

    Status(int aStatus) {
        this.status = aStatus;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

}

class StatusTest3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (Status stat : Status.values()) {
            System.out.println(stat + " value is " + stat.getStatus());
        }
    }
}
```

What does `Status.values()` return ?

and the output is :

```
STATUS_OPEN value is 10
STATUS_STARTED value is 11
STATUS_INPROGRESS value is 12
```

Comment: And your reason why it shouldn't have worked is?!

Comment: you need to study and work a lot more with enums

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

> All the **constants** of an enum type can be obtained by calling the implicit public static T[] values() method of that type.

Comment: but how did it access the values in the brackets ?

Comment: @AjZ You need to do some work around. Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047756/getting-enum-associated-with-int-value

Answer (score 1):

`Status.values()` : will return an array containing the constants of this enum type, in the
 order they're declared

Read JLS for more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2