# Get the name of enum based on the value

Tags: java

I have the following enum

```
public enum AppointmentSlotStatusType {

    INACTIVE(0), ACTIVE(1);

    private int value;

    private AppointmentSlotStatusType(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

How do I get the enum name if a value is known for instance `1` ?

Comment: Implement a `valueOf`-style method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this specific enum it's easy

```
String name = TimeUnit.values()[1].name();
```

Comment: I would add that the `number` field is useless as there is an `ordinal` field already.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It's a bad idea to use `ordinals` for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a `public static` method inside the `enum`, which will give you the enum instance for that id:

```
public static AppointmentSlotStatusType forId(int id) {
    for (AppointmentSlotStatusType type: values()) {
        if (type.value == id) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Probably you would also like to cache the array returned by `values()` in a field:

```
public static final AppointmentSlotStatusType[] VALUES = values();
```

then use `VALUES` instead of `values()`.

---

Or you can use a `Map` instead.

```
private static final Map<Integer, AppointmentSlotStatusType> map = new HashMap<>();

static {
    for (AppointmentSlotStatusType type: values()) {
        map.put(type.value, type);
    }
}

public static AppointmentSlotStatusType forId(int id) {
    return map.get(id);
}
```

Comment: In your opinion, should the method really return `null` or throw an `Exception`?

Comment: If you're going to cache then use a `Map` - that's O(1) instead of O(n)...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I guess there is no issue with returning `null` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a `Map` to hold name for Integer key.

```
public enum AppointmentSlotStatusType {
    INACTIVE(0), ACTIVE(1);

    private int value;

    private static Map<Integer, AppointmentSlotStatusType> map = new HashMap<Integer, AppointmentSlotStatusType>();

    static {
        for (AppointmentSlotStatusType item : AppointmentSlotStatusType.values()) {
            map.put(item.value, item);
        }
    }

    private AppointmentSlotStatusType(final int value) { this.value = value; }

    public static AppointmentSlotStatusType valueOf(int value) {
        return map.get(value);
    }
}
```

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11047810/1651233).

Comment: Why not just vote to close this as a duplicate? Where do you see the difference between this question and the one you linked to?