# how to get enum on the basis of value?

Tags: java, enums

i have a enum

```
public enum Category {
NonResidential("Non-Residential"), Residential("Residential");
private String category;

BuildingAssetCategory(String s) {
    category = s;
}

public String getType() {
    return category;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.category = type;
}
}
```

I want to get the enum on the basis of value its having.
i have `String` of value `Non-Residential`, then how can i get the enum returning `NonResidential.

P.S i to want to create own magic rather then something java supports.
i have read out many question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047756/getting-enum-associated-with-int-value) but i want different ans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic here, since it's your own define field ('category') you should write your own static method to search by it. For example:

```
public enum Category {
  ...
        public static Category findByName(String cat){
            // loop over Category.values() and find the requested cat
        }
```

btw ValueOf will work if you provide the enum name (e.g. "NonResidential") but it won't work for category name (e.g. "non-residential")

Comment: This is correct, I've removed my answer.

Comment: any other way? using setter/getter or something else? which is is builtin not our magic..

Comment: Unfortunately no :(  In java 8 you could write 'smarter' code (using streams instead of a loop), but it's just a matter of taste - anyway you'll still be writing your own method ('findByName').

Answer (score 0):

Use `valueOf`.

```
Category.valueOf("Non-Residential");
```

This will return you the enum.

Comment: same punch, I have also done this but unfortunately it returns `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant` :(